# MPLABX macro expansion

Tags: c, mplabx

I am using MPLABX v2.25 and XC32 compiler v1.33 on a Mac.

Maybe I am not fluent with the use of the preprocessor, but the macro expansion window in MPLABX seems to produce rather unexpected results.

Example-1:

```
#define PIBO TEST  
void ftest(void)  
{  
#if (PIBO == TEST)  
  printf("Hello");  
#endif  
}
```

Expected Result: printf() should appear in the macro expansion window
Result: printf() does appear in the macro expansion window

So far so good.

Example-2:

```
#define PIBO FOOTEST  
void ftest(void)  
{  
#if (PIBO == TEST)  
    printf("Hello");  
#endif  
}
```

Expected Result: printf() should NOT appear in the macro expansion window
Result: printf() does appear in the macro expansion window

Example-3:

```
void ftest(void)  
{  
#if (0)  
    printf("Hello");  
#endif  
}
```

Expected Result: printf() should not appear in the macro expansion window
Result: printf() does not appear in the macro expansion window

Is the MPLAB X macro expansion window showing faults or is it my code or understanding of how this is supposed to work?

Comment: Not sure how the pre-processor would process it exactly but because `==` can't be used for string comparison in C I wouldn't expect it to work. The more usual thing would be to `#define FOOTEST 1` and `#define TEST 2` etc so the comparison is a numeric one.

Comment: In C, undefined symbols in the preprocessor evaluate as `0`. Therefore, your first two examples all evaluate as `0 == 0` which is true. if you `#define x 1` and `#define y 2` then `(x == y)` evaluates as `(1 == 2)` which is false.

Comment: @DoxyLover, I wasn't sure how it handled undefined symbols,  you might as well post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, undefined symbols in the preprocessor evaluate as `0`. Therefore, your first two examples all evaluate as `0 == 0` which is true.

If you

```
#define x 1
```

then

```
#define y 2
```

then `(x == y)` evaluates as `(1 == 2)` which is false.